# Get ViewID in JSF while using templates

Tags: jsf, view, request

I'm trying to get my `RequestID` or `RequestURI` in JSF as soon as I click a button. I tried this:

```
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ExternalContext exContext = context.getExternalContext();
    Map<String, String> x = exContext.getRequestHeaderMap();
    System.out.println(x.get("request"));
    System.out.println(context.getViewRoot().getViewId());
    System.out.println(exContext.getRequestContextPath());
```

The problem is, that my page is a template that reload parts of the side with a new XHTML. The basic side is `home.xhtml` and I get exactly this ID all the time.

But what I need is the XHTML that is included, for example `view1.xhtml` (loaded in `home.xhtml`).

Is that possible? I need this to save the requesting view in my database for my little translation app.

**EDIT:** My WebApp should track, which view has called a special translation tag from my resource bundle and write the view (`view1.xthml`, not `home.xhtml`) and the tag into the database. Maybe its also possible to get the html element ID too (but this it not important)? There are multiple includes on each view!

Example: `login.xhtml` included in `home.xhtml`

```
<p:panel header="#{translations['titel']}">
```

now the app should save (login.xhtml, titel).

Thanks!

**EDIT2:**

XHTML:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

<h:head>
    <title>example</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon"
          href="#{request.contextPath}/resources/images/logo/example.ico"/>
</h:head>

<h:body>
    <h:form id="menubar">
        <p:menubar>
            <p:submenu label="#{translations['language']}" icon="fa fa-language">
                <p:menuitem value="German" action="#{language.setLocale(de)}"/>
                <p:menuitem value="English" action="#{language.setLocale(en)}"/>
            </p:submenu>
        </p:menubar>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

faces-config.xml entry for resource-bundle:

```
<resource-bundle>
    <base-name>example.i18n.resourcebundle.DBResourceBundle</base-name>
    <var>translations</var>
</resource-bundle>
```

Translation-Bean-Function:

```
public String test() {
    FacesContext fCtx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    UIComponent currentComponent = UIComponent.getCurrentComponent(fCtx);
    if (null != currentComponent) {
        Location location = (Location) currentComponent.getAttributes().get(UIComponent.VIEW_LOCATION_KEY);
        if (null != location) {
            System.out.println(location);
            System.out.println(location.getPath());
            return location.getPath();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Now i want to save all the requests of `label="#{translations['language']}"` in a map. This map should have "*language*" as key and the requesting XHTML (for example "*login.xhtml*") as value. Translations contains most of the translations i need, if its not inside i also want an entry as before.

In this case its enough if the request calls the `test()` function.

Comment: Only by retrieving the `ui:include` from the view and look up its value

Comment: 2 questions: 1) is there a function for that? 2) i have multiple includes, how can i differ which one is the correct?

Comment: 1) yes, google for finding component in jsf view. 2) yes by id

Comment: i improved my question a little bit, i think its not what im looking for

Answer (score 0):

While evaluating the `#{translations['titel']}` you want to know the physical location of that expression within an XHTML file.

After digging a bit I found how to get the location of the currently rendered Tag:

For related API see

```
javax.faces.view.Location
UIComponent.VIEW_LOCATION_KEY
javax.faces.component.UIComponent.getCurrentComponent(FacesContext)
```

You can use this pice of code to get the XHTML file name:

```
public String getCurrentComponentPath() {
        FacesContext fCtx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        UIComponent currentComponent = UIComponent.getCurrentComponent(fCtx);
        if (null != currentComponent) {
            Location location = (Location) currentComponent.getAttributes().get(UIComponent.VIEW_LOCATION_KEY);
            if (null != location) {
                return location.getPath();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Tested this with JSF 2.3 (Mojarra).

**Note**: If your EL expression does not reside in a component within the current template, you'll not get the current XHTML file name as `UIComponent.getCurrentComponent` returnes the component from **parent** template XHTML **that includes** the current XHTML.

E.g. this won't work as expected:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets">

<ui:composition>

    #{translations['titel']}

</ui:composition>
</html>
```

While this does:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets">

<ui:composition>

    <h:outputText value="#{translations['titel']}"/>

</ui:composition>
</html>
```

Comment: sorry for the long break! how do i use this function? if i call it with <p:remoteButton> its not executed, if i call it over <p:remoteCommand> i get null. Im a bit confused how to track that outputtext in your example.

Comment: You can replace that source code you have written in your question with `System.out.println(getCurrentComponentPath());`

Comment: yes i did that but i get null as response. i think that happens because i cant use the commandButton without remoteButton (its inside a composite). Can u explain me, how i can track the outputText call of translations['titel']? maybe i can test it this way. Thank you!

Comment: i added more detailed code (EDIT2) hope this will help - thx!